# Consider a matrix with integer entries such that $a_{ii}=1$ and $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix with integer entries such that $a_{ii}=1$ and $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j$

Then

1. $A^{-1}$ exists and it has integers entries.
2. $A^{-1}$ exists and it has some entries which are not integers.
3. $A^{-1}$ exists and it is a polynomial function in $A$ with integers coefficient.
4. $A^{-1}$ is a not a power of $A$ unless $A=I$

As $\det A=1$ so $A$ inverse exist and $A^{-1}=\dfrac{\operatorname{Adj} A}{\det A}$ clearly $A^{-1}$ will have all integer entries, $2$ is false,$c_nA^n+\dots +I=0\Rightarrow A^{-1}=-c_nA^n+\dots+ c_{n-1}A$ as $\det A=c_0=1$ so $3$ is true, say $A^{k-1}=A^{-1}$ then $A^k-I=0$ so minpoly must divide $x^k-1$ and as its charpoly is $(x-1)^n=0$ so minpoly must divide $(x-1)^n$ too but that forces minpoly is $(x-1)$ and hence $A=I$. is my all logics are  okay?

Comment: That seems correct to me.

Comment: It is not clear what your 4 enumerated points are doing. You cannot be claiming 1. as well as 2., nor can you be claiming that exactly one of the four holds (at least that would be false). Please phrase your question so that it is clear what you are asking/saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proofs are correct, apart from some minor issues: the line
$$c_nA^n+\dots +I=0\Rightarrow A^{-1}=-c_nA^n+\dots+ c_{n-1}A$$
should read
$$A^n + c_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1A + c_0I = 0
\ \Rightarrow\ A^{-1} = (-1)^{n+1}(A^{n-1} + c_{n-1}A^{n-2} + \ldots + c_1I)$$
or
$$c_nA^n + c_{n-1}A^{n-1} + \ldots + c_1A + I = 0
\ \Rightarrow\ A^{-1} = -(c_nA^{n-1} + c_{n-1}A^{n-2} + \ldots + c_1I),$$
depending on whether you force the leading term or the constant term to $1$. Also, you need to explain why the coefficients $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ are integers.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need anything involved. $A=I-N$ with $N$ an integer matrix satisfying $N^n=0$. Then by the geometric series $A^{-1}=I+N+N^2+\cdots+N^{n-1}$. Of course $N=I-A$ so any polynomial in $N$ is also a polynomial in $A$.